# I got strange characters to my file. I use unbuffered I/O stream in C language

Tags: c, file, unix, io, stream

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  int i, stream;

  for (i = 20; i < 40; i++) {
    if (i % 2 == 0) {

      stream = open(argv[1], O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, 0644);
      char *x;
      *x = i;
      write(stream, &x, 1024);

      close(stream);
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

I got characters in file like:

```
@^@^@^@^@Z^@^@2@^@^@
```

Comment: You seem to lack a few fundamental concepts of C.   Try and google a few tutorials, and if possible get “The C Programming Language” by Kernigham and Ritchie.   It is well suited as a self guided tutorial with lots of working examples and relevant exercises.   There is a website which proposes solutions to the exercises.   Good luck, C remains a lively and even fun language to program in, and is a great gateway to even more fun languages like Go.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple problems in the code.

**One**

```
char *x;
*x = i;
```

This creates a pointer which doesn't point anywhere, and immediately writes through that pointer. Undefined Behaviour. You probably wanted this:

```
char x = i;
```

**Two**

```
write(stream, &x, 1024);
```

This writes 1024 bytes starting from the address of the variable `x`. In the original case, `x` is a pointer, so it most likely occupies 4 or 8 bytes (depending on if your system is 32-bit or 64-bit, respectively). With the change I suggest above, `x` is a one-byte variable.

In either case, there are no 1024 bytes of data to write. You probably meant this:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  int i, stream;

  for (i = 20; i < 40; i++) {
    if (i % 2 == 0) {

      stream = open(argv[1], O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, 0644);
      char x = i;
      write(stream, &x, 1);

      close(stream);
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Perfect answer, non-aggressive and didactic!! Kudos for you.